# JS or jQuery to compare two texts character by character

Tags: javascript, jquery

It should compare the texts and update it. I am using onkeyup for each time text is updated.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#color").keyup(validate);
});


function validate() {
  var password1 = $("#color").val();
  var pass = $('#coltext').text();
  var length = $("#color").val().length;

  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (pass[i] == password1[i]) {
      $("#coltext").css("color", "green"); //make only correct character green
    } else {
      $("#coltext").css("color", "red");
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="color" type="text" />
<p id="coltext">This</p>
```

So what I want to do is whenever I type the "This" written should update character by character, green for correct and red for wrong. You can say like what typing tutor does.

Comment: If I write "Thus", should only the "u" be in red? Or do you put in red anything after the first error?

Comment: jquery IS js, fyi

Comment: This is slightly more complex than what you might be expecting, because you should not apply the css style to the whole element, but to each character, so you likely need to create a new element each character.

Comment: @MacPrawn only the "u"

Comment: @briosheje Yeah, I supposed so. But even this code is not working and I don't get it why

Comment: You have to use `var i` not `int i` in JS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to break the password into spans in order to style them seperately, then to compare then use `$("#coltext span").eq(i).text()` instead of `pass[i]`;

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#color").keyup(validate);
});


function validate() {
  var password1 = $("#color").val();
  
  // put each of your password chars in a span
  var pass = "<span>"+$('#coltext').text().split("").join("</span><span>")+"</span>";
  $('#coltext').html(pass);
  
  var length = $("#color").val().length;

  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if ($("#coltext span").eq(i).text() == password1[i]) {
      $("#coltext span").eq(i).css("color", "green"); //make only correct character green
    } else {
      $("#coltext span").eq(i).css("color", "red");
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="color" type="text" />
<p id="coltext">This</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
var x = "Cancelled";
var y = "Cancelled";
if(x==y)
{
    alert("equal");
}
else
{
    alert("not equal");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In above example through you can compare two string by using == operators